# pecl install IBM_DB2 Installation Fails with 'make' failed: file not found: mac64/libcilkrts.5.dylib for architecture x86_64

Tags: php, db2, pear

I have IBM DB2 Developer Community Edition installed. DB2 itself works. I want to run PHP scripts on DB2 but need the necessary drivers.

When I run `pecl install ibm_db2` I get the following error:

> ld: file not found: mac64/libcilkrts.5.dylib for architecture x86_64
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> make: *** [ibm_db2.la] Error 1
>
> ERROR: 'make' failed

I tried making a /opt/ibm/dsdriver directory and setting that as the DB2 installation directory but that didn't work. I also tried to point the installation directory at the sqllib directory (which is what you're supposed to do) but that results in a sqllib/lib not found an error. When I googled how to fix the latter, I wound up back at the former error.

Any ideas?

Comment: If the file libcilkrts.5.dylib exists somewhere, try adding its directory-name to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH first.

Comment: The file doesn't exist. I tried using `find / -name "libcilkrts.5.dylib"` and got nothing

Comment: If you have developer skills, try building from source. There are more options available for excluding components or using different libraries. Details at https://github.com/php/pecl-database-ibm_db2